# how to get list of one entity set from another entity set in a many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLa2u.jpg)I am working with controller code in MVC.

I have the follow code working where the are related entities priority list based on teams:

```
public JsonResult GetPrioritiesByTeam(int id)
    {
        List<Priority> priorities = new List<Priority>();
        if (id > 0)
        {
            priorities = db.Priorities.Where(p => p.Team == id ).ToList();

        }
        else
        {
            priorities.Insert(0, new Priority { Id = 0, PriorityDescription = "--Select a Team first--" });
        }
        var result = (from r in priorities
                      select new
                      {
                          id = r.Id,
                          name = r.PriorityDescription
                      }).ToList();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The statement

```
 priorities = db.Priorities.Where(p => p.Team == id
```

does get me the list of priorities based on the team passed in by the parameter id.

I am now try to achieve the same successful result with another entity that is related to team- an entity called 'members'. However the relationship is not a one to many. Its a many to many- so I have an intermediate entity call 'teammembers'.

The Team is still the entity driving the choice. When the team is chosen, I need it to give me all the team member entries in teammembers, and then I need similar to the priorities code above, give me a members list which is based on the teammembers identified based on the team selected.

I think based on the code provided the else clause would be similar coding along with the var result coding.

I just cant seem to get the coding right for the clause in the condition for id >0.

How do I write that clause for the many to many so as to get the list of members for the team through teammembers?

You can assume entity team is Id and TeamDescription, entity Member is Id and MemberName, and entity teammember is an ID,and teamId and MemberId -just a straightforward many to many.

Been trying with LINQ method syntax and LINQ query syntax but cant get it working.

Thanks for any help you can provide

New code would look like the following except i need working id>0 clause:

```
public JsonResult GetMembersByTeam(int id)
    {
        List<Member> members = new List<Member>();




        if (id > 0)
        {
            **members = Members.Where(needed clause).ToList();**
        }

        else
        {
            members.Insert(0, new Member { Id = 0, MemberFullName = "--Select a Team first--" });
        }
        var result = (from m in members

                      select new
                      {
                          id = m.Id,
                          name = m.MemberFullName
                      }).ToList();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

[Entity Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLa2u.jpg)

Current code with suggested changes

```
public JsonResult GetMembersByTeam(int id)
    {
        List<Member> members = new List<Member>();


        if (id > 0)
        {


            //members = db.Teams.Where(p => p.Id == id)
            //    .SelectMany(e => e.TeamMembers)
            //    .Select(e => e.Member)
            //    .ToList();

            members = db.TeamMembers.Where(p => p.Team == id)
.Select(e => e.Member)
.ToList();

        }
        else
        {
            members.Insert(0, new Member { Id = 0, MemberFullName = "--Select a Team first--" });
        }
        var result = (from m in members

                      select new
                      {
                          id = m.Id,
                          name = m.MemberFullName
                      }).ToList();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

results in error :

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List,ManageHR5.model.Member>'

Comment: pls add entity models to question

Comment: added Entity Diagram link above. Team has other related entities, but not germain to the issue of having similar code to above example where members are identified by team initially selected and that passing through teammembers enitity. The end result is for a dropdown list of members which would be returned by the return statement,

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
members = db.TeamMembers.Where(p => p.Team == id )
    .Select(e => e.Member1)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks Mohammad, both versions give the impression that they would work when I put them in the controller code, but I am  now coming up with another error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ManageHR5.Models.Member>' ManageHR5 C:\Users\Lyndon.A3HR\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ManageHR5\ManageHR5\Controllers\ServiceRequestsController.cs 296 Active

Comment: Thanks much. That worked! I need to get more familiar with MVC and enitity framework. Again thanks ...